# squashmigrations useage (how to find 'migration_name')

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm using Django 1.8.

When running `python manage.py squashmigrations myapp` I get this:

```
manage.py squashmigrations: error: the following arguments are required: migration_name
```

How do I find the **migration_name**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This was actually a trivial question.  I could also have just looked in the
`\myproject\myapp\migrations\` folder where all the migration files are kept (or looked in the database with psql).

This is my workaround for now:

```
(venv) mydir> python manage.py squashmigrations myapp 0006
Will squash the following migrations:
 - 0001_initial
 - 0002_auto_20150809_2248
 - 0003_answer
 - 0004_auto_20150812_0305
 - 0005_auto_20150812_0601
 - 0006_auto_20150812_1903
Do you wish to proceed? [yN] N
```

I just guessed at how many time I've run `migrate` and fortunately it prompts me before doing anything.  So now I just need to keep guessing until I see something like `CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching '0021' from app 'myapp'` .

Comment: This seems like bothersome way to do it. I have added a new answer :)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest two options to find the name of the migrations are:

1. Look in your `migrations` folder in your app directory
2. Run `python manage.py showmigrations <app_name>` to show all migrations for the app, and whether they are applied.

**Tip:**
You can use unique prefixes in your definition of the exact migration. For example if you have the following migrations in your app:

```
0001_initial
0002_auto_20150809_2248
0003_answer
0004_auto_20150812_0305
```

and you want to squash up to `0004_auto_20150812_0305` you just run

```
python manage.py showmigrations <app_name> 0004
```

In some cases however you may have more than one migration with a certain number. This can happens you merge two VCS branches where the migrations were created with the same number. Fortunately Django can often handle this automatically by running `makemigrations --merge`, and you may end up with:

```
0001_initial
0002_auto_20150809_2248
0003_answer
0004_auto_20150812_0305
0006_auto_20150812_0601
0006_cleanup
0007_merge
```

In this case you should really squash to the merge migration, but if you need to target one of the `0006` ones specifically, just use enough of the name so that Django can distinguish. Using `0006_a` should be enough to target `0006_auto_20150812_0601`.
This works for the `migrate` command as well.

Comment: In case you don't have any migration, try "python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>". Then you'll see "0001_initial" when running "python manage.py showmigrations <app_name>".

Comment: @Donald Well, then there would be no reason for squashing, right?

Answer (score 1):

the migration_name is the number head of the files locate in yourapp/migrations/

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate asset 0001
ll asset/migrations/
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1326 Feb  9 20:17 0001_initial.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1405 Feb  9 20:20 0001_initial.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Feb  5 06:07 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  140 Feb  5 06:48 __init__.pyc
```

asset is my app and 0001 is the migration_name

Comment: It is possible to get two migrations with the same number. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the files in you app_name/migrations. The migration_name should be "0001_initial" etc

Answer (score 0):

To find out programatically in a script you can use

```
./manage.py migrate --list <app_name> | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

For a bunch of apps

```
APPS="asset common product"

for APP in $APPS
do
    # find out the latest migration
    MIGRATION_NAME=`./manage.py migrate -l $APP | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
    ./manage.py squashmigrations $APP $MIGRATION_NAME
done
```